# Remove a tile from layer Cocos2D iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I want to be able to remove a tile from my game when my player touches it. The only way I have found is to hide the whole layer which is not what I want to do.

I have the collision detection working fine, I just need to be able to remove the tile on collision or when the player/sprite gets to that position.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: set gid at that position to 0

Answer (score 0):

You can remove tiles with:

```
[_layer removeTileAt:CGPointOfTile];
```